# Randomizing foreach expression and including URL redirection

Tags: php, random

This might be a little complicated..!

Here's what I got so far:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $link = $post[1];
    $title = $post[2];

    $i++; 

    //echo $link;
}
```

`$i` = Counts all posts on my website.

`$link` = provide a link to the post.

After fetching how many posts I have with `$i`, I need to randomize a value between 1-"Total Posts" and instead of echoing out the random value it should redirect the website to the respective `$link`. Can someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) to obtain a random key in `$posts`

```
$posts = array (
  array ('0', 'http://stackoverflow.com', 'SO'),
  array ('1', 'http://google.com',    'Google'),
  array ('2', 'http://youtube.com',  'Youtube'),
  array ('3', 'http://4chan.org',      '4chan')
);

// ...

$random_entry_key = array_rand ($posts);
$random_entry     = $posts[$random_entry_key];

header ("Location: " . $random_entry[1]);
```

If you have a fetish for one-liners `header("Location: ".$posts[array_rand ($posts)][1]);`

Comment: Tough choice, everyone gave creative answers but this one wins the trophy for the most simple, functional and different! Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

```
$i = rand(0, count($posts) - 1); // if $posts has 10 items, rand will return
                                 // an integer between 0 and 9 (both inclusive)
header('Location: ' . $posts[$i][1]);
```

Comment: Might work in this case. Does not not work with associative arrays or arrays with gaps.