# Best approach to preventing array_rand from generating the same link?

Tags: php

This is a follow-up question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455648/randomizing-foreach-expression-and-including-url-redirection).

The code is working great, it randoms the link to a blog post. The downside is that I may fall into the same post twice or too often.

```
header("Location: ".$posts[array_rand ($posts)][1]);
```

I need it to not fall on the same post more than once every 20 minutes, if runs out of posts then say: "Out of options. Come back in 20 minutes.". I tried doing it with cookies like so:

```
$rlink = $posts[array_rand ($posts)][1];

setcookie("rlink", "$rlink", time()+1200);

if ($rlink == $_COOKIE["rlink"]) {
  header('Location: http://localhost/randommyblog.php');   
} else
{
header("Location: ".$rlink);
}
```

It might be obvious that the problem here is that I'm replacing the cookie "rlink" every time, rendering the previous one useless.

Little help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this, worked when I tested it as is:

```
$posts = array("hello", "world", "it's", "me" ); 

$len_posts = count( $posts );

$set_indices = @$_COOKIE['rlink']; 

$rand = mt_rand( 0, $len_posts - 1 ); //Select a random index from the post

if( !empty( $set_indices ) )
{
    $set_indices = array_map( "intval", explode( ",", $set_indices ) );
    $len_indices = count( $set_indices );


    if( $len_indices >= $len_posts )
    {
        die("no posts for you");
    }
    else
    {
        while( in_array( $rand, $set_indices, TRUE ) ) //Calculate a new index that has not been shown.
        {
            $rand = mt_rand( 0, $len_posts - 1 );
        }


    }
}
else
{
    $set_indices = array();
}

array_push( $set_indices, $rand );

setcookie( "rlink", implode( ",", $set_indices ), time()+1200 ); //Set cookie of the shown indices like "3,0,1" for example.

echo $posts[$rand];
```

Comment: This works and is near perfect, when it runs out of links it keeps loading forever though and shows error 500. Any way to echo "Ran out" instead of this error?

Comment: @Sara, what do you have in the `if( $len_indices === $len_posts )` block? Is your posts array one-dimensional 0-indexed?

Comment: `echo "Sorry, rand out of posts, come back after 20 minutes.";`  But instead of showing this echo it keeps loading for 20 seconds or something and then it shows error 500.

Comment: @Sara, do `die()` as shown in my example. And let me fix one other thing :P I changed `===` to `>=` because your cookie had more posts than exists so the loop was inifinite.. the reason your cookie had more posts because you used `echo` instead of `die()`.